# Which layout should replace LinearLayout in this calculator

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-constraintlayout

I've implemented this simple calculator layout using `LinearLayout`, but faced with "nested weights" warning from Android Studio.

This is my first attempt to do something for android, so I started reading: `TableLayout` and `GridLayout` would have the same problem as I understand, and `ConstraintLayout` is recommended everywhere.

But I can't figure it out, how to achieve the same result using `ConstraintLayout`.
Is it possible? Is it even worth it to ditch `LinearLayout` in this case?

[image]

My layout:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:paddingRight="0dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="#F5F5F6"

        >
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            tools:text="2 + 2"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            tools:text="4"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        >
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            >
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@color/colorAccent"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                >

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/keyboard_num7"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="7"
                    style="@style/Operand"
                    />
                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/keyboard_num8"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="8"
                    style="@style/Operand"
                    />
                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/keyboard_num9"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="9"
                    style="@style/Operand"
                    />
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@color/colorAccent"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                >

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/keyboard_num4"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="4"
                    style="@style/Operand"
                    />
                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/keyboard_num5"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="5"
                    style="@style/Operand"
                    />
                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/keyboard_num6"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="6"
                    style="@style/Operand"
                    />
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@color/colorAccent"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                >

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/keyboard_num1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="1"
                    style="@style/Operand"
                    />
                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/keyboard_num2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="2"
                    style="@style/Operand"
                    />
                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/keyboard_num3"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="3"
                    style="@style/Operand"
                    />
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@color/colorAccent"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                >

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/keyboard_num_dot"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="."
                    style="@style/Operand"
                    />
                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/keyboard_num0"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="0"
                    style="@style/Operand"
                    />
                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/keyboard_num_del"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="del"
                    style="@style/Operand"
                    />
            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:background="#E1E2E1"
            >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/keyboard_division"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="÷"
                style="@style/Operator"
                />
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/keyboard_multiplication"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                style="@style/Operator"
                android:text="×"
                />
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/keyboard_minus"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                style="@style/Operator"
                android:text="−"
                />
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/keyboard_plus"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                style="@style/Operator"
                android:text="+"
                />
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/keyboard_equal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                style="@style/Equal"
                android:text="="
                />

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Have you found anything in ConstraintLayout that prevented you from doing this?

Comment: @MartinMarconcini no, my lack of knowledge was preventing me. Now I did it (see my answer below), but still have many questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, to answer my own question "how to achieve the same result using `ConstraintLayout`"

I've made it flat using `ConstraintLayout`, but still don't know whether it was worth it, and how to decide which layout to use when you can use any.

And is using guidelines with `app:layout_constraintGuide_percent` and/or `chainStyle="spread_inside"` with 0 size is somehow better than "nested weights" from performance point of view.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guidelineH"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.33"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        />
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guidelineV"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.75"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/formula"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/result"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed"
        tools:text="2+2"
        android:textSize="36sp"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/result"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/formula"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/guidelineH"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed"
        tools:text="4"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/keyboard_num7"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/keyboard_num4"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/keyboard_num8"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/guidelineH"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread_inside"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="spread_inside"
        android:text="7"
        style="@style/Operand"
        />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/keyboard_num8"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/keyboard_num5"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/keyboard_num7"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/keyboard_num9"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/guidelineH"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread_inside"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="spread_inside"
        android:text="8"
        style="@style/Operand"
        />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/keyboard_num9"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/keyboard_num6"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/keyboard_num8"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/guidelineV"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/guidelineH"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread_inside"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="spread_inside"
        android:text="9"
        style="@style/Operand"
        />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/keyboard_num4"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/keyboard_num1"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/keyboard_num5"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/keyboard_num7"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread_inside"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="spread_inside"
        android:text="4"
        style="@style/Operand"
        />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/keyboard_num5"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/keyboard_num2"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/keyboard_num4"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/keyboard_num6"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/keyboard_num8"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread_inside"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="spread_inside"
        android:text="5"
        style="@style/Operand"
        />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/keyboard_num6"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/keyboard_num3"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/keyboard_num5"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/guidelineV"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/keyboard_num9"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread_inside"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="spread_inside"
        android:text="6"
        style="@style/Operand"
        />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/keyboard_num1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/keyboard_num_dot"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/keyboard_num2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/keyboard_num4"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread_inside"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="spread_inside"
        android:text="1"
        style="@style/Operand"
        />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/keyboard_num2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/keyboard_num0"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/keyboard_num1"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/keyboard_num3"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/keyboard_num5"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread_inside"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="spread_inside"
        android:text="2"
        style="@style/Operand"
        />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/keyboard_num3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/keyboard_num_del"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/keyboard_num2"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/guidelineV"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/keyboard_num6"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread_inside"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="spread_inside"
        android:text="3"
        style="@style/Operand"
        />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/keyboard_num_dot"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/keyboard_num0"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/keyboard_num1"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread_inside"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="spread_inside"
        android:text="."
        style="@style/Operand"
        />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/keyboard_num0"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/keyboard_num_dot"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/keyboard_num_del"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/keyboard_num2"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread_inside"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="spread_inside"
        android:text="0"
        style="@style/Operand"
        />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/keyboard_num_del"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/keyboard_num0"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/guidelineV"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/keyboard_num3"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread_inside"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="spread_inside"
        android:text="del"
        style="@style/Operand"
        />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/keyboard_division"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/keyboard_multiplication"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/guidelineH"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/guidelineV"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread_inside"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="spread_inside"
        android:text="÷"
        style="@style/Operator"
        />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/keyboard_multiplication"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/keyboard_minus"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/keyboard_division"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/guidelineV"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread_inside"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="spread_inside"
        style="@style/Operator"
        android:text="×"
        />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/keyboard_minus"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/keyboard_plus"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/keyboard_multiplication"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/guidelineV"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread_inside"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="spread_inside"
        style="@style/Operator"
        android:text="−"
        />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/keyboard_plus"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/keyboard_equal"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/keyboard_minus"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/guidelineV"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread_inside"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="spread_inside"
        style="@style/Operator"
        android:text="+"
        />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/keyboard_equal"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/keyboard_plus"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/guidelineV"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread_inside"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="spread_inside"
        style="@style/Equal"
        android:text="="
        />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: A few comments: 1. remember not to use left/right anywhere, replace them with start/End. (Unless you target API 16<).

Comment: Is chains/guidlines better than nested weights? Yes. The time it takes Android to display a layout is heavily influenced by the depth of the layout (nested stuff), because all these are really List<View> in the end, and said lists have to be iterated N times. Now, there's another aspect that is not only about the depth ...

Comment: ... and that is, the Measure pass (to measure how much space a widget needs/have), and then a Layout pass (to decide where to put each widget, in relation to the other(s)). Now these take time, to measure you have to go through each view and ask "what size do you need?", all taking into account the _other views_. Then once you know this, you have to see: "Does this fit?" because a view can ask for 1000px but if there are only 100 available.. what should the engine do? This means you have to transverse the view hierarchy and iterate those views...

Comment: Additionally, these views may "WRAP CONTENT" so... you don't know yet how much space they need... in the end, all this takes time and if there's a change (say you change the size of a view), the whole thing has to be recomputed. THIS is where Constraint Laytou offers benefits. First is flat(ter) so that means less nested iterations. But also it's resolved by the Cassowary's algorithm (iirc), which means you supply some input and you get the output(s). In my experience, this is often much faster than any other form of layout (short for small LinearLayouts...)

Comment: In Conclusion, it's likely better, but in practice, you have to consider if your constraint layout is super complicated or has also too much nesting (sometimes needed), then it may not be more performant. Weights are very heavy (due to the fact that a lot of calculation must be done prior to knowing how much space is there to "weight"). All in all, I'd use the ConstraintLayout version if possible.